# Converting XML string to JSON

Tags: json, xml, node.js

I am making an API request to the Census API for my Node app. The response I am receiving is an XML string:

```
"[["POP","DATE","state"],
["735132","6","02"],
["735132","6","02"]]"
```

I would like to convert it into JSON. I have tried using npm xml2js but I am receiving the following error: 
 "Non-whitespace before first tag.
Line: 0
Column: 1 
I dont understand XML, so its makes it difficult to comprehend the error message. Any good ideas how I can convert this response to JSON? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you think it's an XML stirng if it's a JSON string? Just do a `JSON.parse(your_string)`

Comment: If that's an XML response, I'm losing my mind.... @VsevolodGoloviznin your comment should work

Comment: Your example is **not** an XML string. That's why you can't convert is using xml2js

Comment: Sorry. I figured an JSON response would be an object {} rather than an array []

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not getting a XML response. It's a parsed JSON string.

So if you want a JSON Object:

```
var response = "[["POP","DATE","state"], ["735132","6","02"], ["735132","6","02"]]";
var json = JSON.parse(response);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is JSON. The problem is it has 2 extra double quotes, at the beginning and the end.

You can do:

```
var string = stringFromAPI;
var sringWithoutExtraDoubleQuotes = string.substring(1, string.length - 1);
var parsedObject = JSON.parse(sringWithoutExtraDoubleQuotes);
```

Comment: Node might actually parse it without removing the extra double quotes.